# Grunt - Can you call grunt-contrib-copy from within a custom registered task and customize the copy on the fly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I know I can setup a task in grunt.config that will grunt-contrib-copy files from src to dest, and looking through Grunt docs I know I can copy single files using grunt.file.copy.

But, is it possible to create grunt-contrib-copy tasks on the fly in a custom registered task to accommodate arguments being sent from the bash?  I want to create a new directory grunt.file.mkdir("some/path/appfoldername") and then copy files to that folder from another destination, but I won't know the folder name until after the custom task is run.  So something like:

```
grunt create_app:appfoldername
```

So I could copy single files over one at a time, but the files will change so want the power of grunt-contrib-copy, but with the flexibility of a custom registered task.

I imagine something like this if my explanation isn't clear enough:

```
grunt.registerTask('createCopy', 'Create a copy', function(folderName) {

    var cwd = grunt.template.process("some/path/to/app");
    var src = grunt.template.process("some/path/to/src");
    var dest = grunt.template.process("some/path/to/dest") + folderName;

    grunt.task.run('copy: {  
       files: { 
          cwd: cwd,
          src: src,
          dest: dest
       }           
    }');
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
grunt.registerTask('mkapp', 'Create Application', function(appName) {

    // Check appName is not empty or undefined
    if(appName !== "" && appName !== undefined) { 

        // Require node path module, since not a global
        var path = require("path");

        // Resolve directory path using templates
        var relPath = grunt.template.process("<%= root %>/<%= dirs.src %>/application/");
        var srcPath = relPath + "default_install";
        var destPath = relPath + appName;

        // Create new application folder
        grunt.file.mkdir(destPath, 0444);

        // Return unique array of all file paths which match globbing pattern
        var options = { cwd: srcPath, filter: 'isFile' };
        var globPattern = "**/*"

        grunt.file.expand(options, globPattern).forEach(function(srcPathRelCwd) {

            // Copy a source file to a destination path, creating directories if necessary
            grunt.file.copy(
                path.join(srcPath, srcPathRelCwd), 
                path.join(destPath, srcPathRelCwd)
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just call [grunt.file.expand](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) on the file specs and then loop over the resulting array, copying them however you like.

```
grunt.file.expand(specs).forEach(function(src) {
  grunt.file.copy(src, dest);
});
```

Comment: Hi @ryanb, I've tried a couple variations, but I can't figure out what the options should be set to? Even using http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand so I added my code above in case that helps.

Comment: If I remove grunt.file.copy(src, destPath) and leave the writeln() it displays all the file paths, and I can write out the destPath as well.

Comment: It appears not to like the folders? Keeps saying "Warning: Unable to read 'cache' file (Error code: ENOENT).", but when I remove the cache folder it then throws an error on the next folder config.

Comment: Got it! Phew, posting result in update above for anyone that wants to duplicate this solution.  Thanks to @ryanb

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work cross-platform, you can use Node's path API to create the file paths with correct path separators and such.

```
grunt.file.expand(options, globPattern).forEach(function(srcPathRelCwd) {
    // Copy a source file to a destination path, creating directories if necessary
    grunt.file.copy(
        path.join(srcPath, srcPathRelCwd), 
        path.join(destPath, srcPathRelCwd)
    );
});
```

Comment: and don't forget that join is not a global module, and it needs to be required using var path = require("path");